# Qual é a diferença entre o particípio presente e o gerúndio?

Tags: verbos, gerúndios

Descobri que em inglês há o particípio presente e o gerúndio, mesmo ambos tendo o mesmo sufixo {-ing} (ex.: *doing*). Então, tentei entender a diferença.

Acabei por me confundir ainda mais, pois, o particípio presente dos exemplos era traduzível para o gerúndio português. Ex.:

> I wasn't listening → Eu não estava ouvindo
>
> The survey revealed some worrying results → A pesquisa revelou alguns resultados preocupando.
>
> The people wanting cake went to the bakery → As pessoas querendo bolo foram à padaria

Na realidade, *a growing problem is at our hands* é traduzível para *um problema crescendo está em nossas mãos*.

Então pergunto, qual é a diferença entre o particípio o presente e o passado? Se possível, qual o argumento para os verbos portugueses terminando em {-ndo} também não serem chamados de particípio presente, como em inglês?

Comment: Os termos "worrying" e "growing" não são verbos, mas sim adjetivos com o sufixo "-ing". Deixo aqui mais informação sobre esse assunto: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/adjectives-ending-in-ed-and-ing

Comment: @Rye Pois é, **você está repetindo o que eu disse e expliquei na minha resposta**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**De uma forma simples e objetiva.**

Na língua inglesa, o gerúndio pode ser sujeito de um verbo, objeto de um verbo ou preposição, complemento, ou parte de uma palavra composta. O importante é que, quase sempre, ele é traduzido para o português como um verbo no infinitivo.

Exemplos:

- **Travelling** during the colder months is not advisable. (Viajar durante os meses mais frios não é aconselhável)
- **Smoking** is not allowed here. (Não é permitido fumar aqui.)
- I've bought a **washing**-machine (Comprei uma máquina de lavar)
- She left the meeting without **saying** a word. (Ela saiu da reunião sem dizer uma palavra.)

**Em português, as traduções acima não correspondem ao nosso gerúndio, e sim a verbos no infinitivo.**

já aquilo que é chamado de particípio presente em inglês, é simplesmente o nosso gerúndio. Geralmente é precedido pelo verbo "to be".

- What were you **doing** when he arrived?  (O que você estava fazendo quando ele chegou?)
- She must be **joking**. (Ela deve estar brincando.)
- I was **travelling** at that time. (Eu estava viajando naquela ocasião)

Em tempo: algumas de suas traduções não estão corretas.

- worrying results = resultados preocupantes
- the people wanting cake = as pessoas que queriam bolo
- a growing problem = um problema que cresce

Quanto à sua pergunta, "qual o argumento para os verbos portugueses terminando em {-ndo} também não serem chamados de particípio presente, como em inglês?";
posso responder que, quando eu era criança, em meu terceiro ou quarto ano de escola elementar, aprendi que "falando" e "andando" eram verbos no particípio presente e que "falado" e "andado" eram particípio passado.  Uns três ou quatro anos mais tarde, as escolas receberam uma diretriz do MEC mudando o termo "particípio presente" para "gerúndio".  O motivo, não sei.

Mais sobre particípio passado e gerúndio na língua inglesa  [**aqui**](https://portlandenglish.edu/blog/difference-gerund-present-participle/#:%7E:text=Improve%20My%20English%3F-,What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20a%20gerund%20and%20a%20present,like%20a%20verb%20or%20adjective.)

**post scriptum**:
**Quando o gerúndio assume o papel de um adjetivo em inglês, procuramos um adjetivo equivalente em português**. Para "worrying", temos o adjetivo "preocupante". Se essa palavra não existisse em português, optaríamos por "que preocupam". É o caso de "a growing problem" onde a melhor tradução é "que cresce" ao invés de "crescente", ou the people wanting cake" onde "as pessoas que querem ou queriam bolo, soa muito melhor do que "as pessoas querendo bolo". Resumindo, procure sempre o adjetivo de uso corrente em português. Caso naõ exista, ou soe estranho no contexto, use uma "relative clause" ("pronome relativo + verbo conjugado")  como, por exemplo, "que querem bolo"

Comment: Obrigadíssimo, Centaurus, pela resposta. Recentemente vi no CiberDúvidas que «o dicionário Batatas, contendo três palavras, foi destruído» está errado, sendo o correto «o dicionário Batatas, que contém três palavras, foi destúido». Porém, ele é usado assim em matérias telejornalísticas, por exemplo.

Comment: Não existe verbo "no particípio presente" porque não é um tempo de verbo.

Comment: Centaurus, uma pergunta, que me esqueci de fazer: por que essas três traduções estão erradas?

Comment: Porque você não sabia que em inglês, um gerúndio pode ser adjetivo. worrying e growing= adjectives in those sentences. As I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Gerunds in English can be used as **nouns or adjectives.**

- That **painting** is good. [substantivo]
- Esse **quadro** é bom. [no sentido de pintura; se traduz por um substantivo normal]
- **Hunting** is really a passé thing.
- **Caçar** já é coisa do passado. [isso se chama "derivação impropria" em português e se trata de usar um verbo com substantivo]
- **Playing** **tennis** is fun. [substantivo]
- **Jogar têni**s é divertido.
- **Parachuting** is a dangerous sport. [substantivo]
- **O parachutismo** é um esporte perigoso.

[formação das palavras](https://www.robertoavila.com.br/aulas/gramatica/Gramatica_08A.pdf)

- The **sleeping** dog was very funny. [adjetivo]
- O cachorro **adormecido** era muito engraçado. [também poderia ser: que estava dormindo]
- The **lying witness** just kept talking. [adjetivo]
- A testemunh**a mentirosa** simplesmente continuo falando. [ou que **estava mentindo**]

Nota-se que o uso do partícipio presente em inglês como adjetivo, muitas vezes, é um encurtamento de uma forma verbal: The witness who was lying just kept talking. As vezes fica melhor traduzir usando uma oração subordinada do que um adjetivo.

O presente e o passado contínuo em ingles também usa esta forma com ing. Nesse casos são parallelos os tempos dos verbos em português:

- The dog **is sleeping** on the floor. [O cachorro está dormindo no chãp]
- The dog **was sleeping** on the floor. [O cachorro estava dormindo no chão]

Conclusão: Os gerúndios em inglês funcionam como substantivos ou adjetivos. Podem ser traduzidos por subtantivos ou verbos "substantivados" no caso de um substantivo e por adjetivos ou orações subordinadas no caso de um adjetivo.

[Em usos verbais: are going, is leaving, etc. se trata de um tempo completo, composto por o verbo be no presente ou passado + o sufixo ing.]

Existe também uns usos mais literários:

Running down street, she started shouting at passersby.
Correndo pela rua abaixo, ela começou a gritar com os transuentes.

Esse último caso também é parecido à forma em português.